# odoo- How can I get data from incoming emails to many2one and data fields?

Tags: python, odoo

In Applicant  I have added  so I can get data to specific field from incoming email ( name : phone: experience ....) but this works just for fields of type char not for many2one field as type_id and  date fields : date_candidature.

```
def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg, custom_values=None, context=None):
    """ Overrides mail_thread message_new that is called by the mailgateway
        through message_process.
        This override updates the document according to the email.
    """
    if custom_values is None:
        custom_values = {}
    val = msg.get('from').split('<')[0]
    val1 = msg.get('from').split('<')[1]
    val2 = val1.split('>')[0]
    myString2 = msg.get('body') if msg.get('body') else ''
    phone = myString2.split('PHONE: ')[1]
    phone2 = phone.split('<br')[0]
    ecole = myString2.split('ETABLISSEMENT: ')[1]
    ecole2 = ecole.split('<br')[0]
    email = myString2.split('EMAIL: ')[1]
    email2 = email.split('<br')[0]
    dispo = myString2.split('DISPO: ')[1]
    dispo2 = dispo.split('<br')[0]
    salaire = myString2.split('REMUNERATION: ')[1]
    salaire2 = salaire.split('<br')[0]
    idcand = myString2.split('IDCANDIDATURE: ')[1]
    id2 = idcand.split('-{')[0]
    datecand = myString2.split('DATECANDIDATURE: ')[1]
    date2 = datecand.split('<br')[0]
    experience = myString2.split('EXPERIENCE: ')[1]
    experience2 = experience.split('<br')[0]
    defaults = {
        'name':  msg.get('subject') or _("No Subject"),
        'partner_name': val,
        'email_from': email2,
        'email_cc': msg.get('cc'),
        'user_id': False,
        'partner_id': msg.get('author_id', False),
        'description': myString2 or '',
        'candidat_mobile': phone2 or '',
        'candidat_ecole': ecole2 or '',
        'av2': dispo2 or '',
        'av3': salaire2 or '',
        'id_candidature': id2 or '',
        'type_id': self.browse(cr, uid, ids).type_id.write({'name': experience2}),
}
    if msg.get('priority'):
        defaults['priority'] = msg.get('priority')
    defaults.update(custom_values)
    return super(hr_applicant, self).message_new(cr, uid, msg, custom_values=defaults, context=context)
```

Comment: in the logger check the value of phone and also use 'candidat_phone': phone or ' '

Comment: thks @Sharma it works but just for char fields but not many2one and date_field